# Cleaning data more efficiently in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a python script that pulls EPS information from streetinsider.com. Currently I'm cleaning the data using an entirely inefficient method as seen below. Wondering if someone can show how this can be done more efficiently.

The following example is very very scaled down, there are many more columns and many many more rows.

```
eps_table = DataFrame({'% Beat': '+1,405%', '% Week': '+123%'}, index=[0])

things_to_remove = ['% Beat', '% Week']
for i in things_to_remove:
    eps_table[i] = eps_table[i].replace("%", "",regex=True)
    eps_table[i] = eps_table[i].replace("\+", "", regex=True)
    eps_table[i] = eps_table[i].replace("\,", "", regex=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it all at once:

```
eps_table.replace(r'[%+,]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Oh, yes! Much better +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way to do it:

```
eps_table.replace('\+', '', regex=True).replace('%', '', regex=True).replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
    % Beat % Week
0   1405    123
```